# get iframe content as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, rich-text-editor, sceditor

I use a jquery plugin for generating rich text editor. That editor generates an structure like this:

```
<div id="editor" ... >
   ...
   <iframe>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
         <head>...</head>
         <body>
            //some important content here and I need to get them
         </body>
      </html>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Now, I want to get everything inside iframe's body as an **String**. I tested `$("#editor").contents().find("body")`, but this return me an object, not string. Also tried `$("#editor").contents().find("body").outerHTML`, but this return me `undefined`. How can I do this? Please help me. Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**

I use [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) plugin. As Ramesh said, I used `val()` method, but still return me `(an empty string)` in the firebug console. Here is my code:

```
var instance = $("textarea").sceditor({
        plugins: "bbcode",
        style: "../../editor/minified/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css",
        //some othe options
    });
    $("#save").click(function(){
        console.log(instance.val());
    });
```

As Ramesh suggests, I used `$('textarea').sceditor('instance').val()` and it worked.

Comment: What is the plugin you are using. Most likely, it would expose a method to fetch the content of the Rich text box. I would advice not to read the iframe content directly.

Comment: I use [SCeditor](http://www.sceditor.com/). I checked api but nothing useful found.

Comment: You may have to update your question to clearly capture that you need content of you SCeditor rich text box and not that of iframe. As the title is misleading and the answers you have got so far are for fetching contents of iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SCEditor to fetch the value of the rich text box, you have to use the [`.val`](http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/val/) method

> val() Since: 1.3.5
>
> Gets the current value of the editor.
>
> This will return the filtered HTML from the WYSIWYG editor or the
>   unfiltered contents of the source editor.
>
> If using a plugin that filters the HTML like the BBCode plugin, this
>   will return the filtered HTML or BBCode in the case of the BBCode
>   plugin.
>
> Syntax
>
> `var val = instance.val();`
>
> Return Type: `String`
>
> The filtered value of the editor

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what is `instance` in your code?

Comment: @hamed try `$('textarea').sceditor('instance').val()`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects are array like objects, and you can access the `innerHTML` property by index (take a look at the console output):

```js
console.log($('iframe')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
   <iframe>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
         <head></head>
         <body>
            some important content here and I need to get them
         </body>
      </html>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested, but show `an empty string` in the console.

Comment: I'll admit I'm not sure why, I just checked in Firefox, Chrome, and Spartan and they all show.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var contain = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML ;
// Use contain where need .
```

*Note : Work only if the `iframe` source is in the same domain.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the iframe does not have ID, so I can't use `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
// Gives you the DOM element without the outside wrapper you want
$('.classSelector').html()

// Gives you the inside wrapper as well
$('.classSelector')[0].innerHTML
```