# Get html from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How to retrieve html code from an iframe ?

I try:

```
$('#iframe').innerHtml
$('#iframe').contents()
```

Its not works.

Have you a idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get iframe content as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116410/get-iframe-content-as-string)

Answer (score 4):

Due to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) you can only access the content if the iframe is on the same domain.

The following javascript will work if it's the same domain:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```